# Syncing between two databases

Tags: database, data-synchronization

I have an application that also has a web interface, one of the requirements is to be able to work on the application even if there isn't an internet connection available.
Is there a need to sync between those databases?
Those databases are ought to be pretty big disk space wise.
If there is such a need how should it be done? What database should I use?
The target OS is windows but the server could run on windows or linux.<

Comment: What kind of database software?

Comment: I need advice on that as well...

Comment: Why do I have a feeling this is going to have a bounty?
Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean you need to be able to work via the web application even when offline? Sounds like you need [Google Gears](http://gears.google.com/) or another [HTML5 structured storage](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#structured-client-side-storage) implementation.

If you using a native app when offline, then yes, it sounds like you'll want a local database for that too.

Do the users typically know when they're going to go offline? If so, you could let them "check out" the subset of the database they're going to need, then later "go online" and synchronize.  Otherwise, you may want to synchronize data that they've used recently, but purge the local database of data they haven't used for a long time.

Quite how hard that will be will depend on your exact application. Do multiple users need to be able to work on the same set of records simultaneously, for example?

Comment: and i'm laffing at those two comments.

Comment: I'm using a native app on one client-end and a web app on the second client-end.
If the connection for some reason is down the program should still be able to work.
Yes, multiple users can edit the same record.
Should I just save the actions of each user and then compute the steps. Basically most steps are minor caclulations.
Should I do this in a view?